# Server error when searching in chat

Tags: bug, chat, 500-server-error

I just tried to make a search on Meta Stack Exchange Chat by typing into the search box in the top right in a chat room, but I got a server error when doing so: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/search

Update: Looks like this is happening with Stack Exchange Chat and Stack Overflow Chat as well.

Update 2: Looks like this question is missing the "Related Questions".

Comment: [Link to reproduce](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=borked&room=89)

Comment: Maybe it's a feature

Comment: @sumelic Didn't file a report because Nick Craver tweeted about it. He didn't say anything about chat search and server errors, though.

Comment: Appears to work again